# Docker nginx + php-fpm config hosts?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am trying to set up a work environment for myself.
I can’t get to the server through the name specified in hosts file.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
```

php dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

./hosts/hello-dev.conf:

```
server {
    server_name hello.dev;
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/hello.dev;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

hosts: `127.0.0.1   hello.dev`

Tell me what you can try to do in this situation?
If I go to the address http://127.0.0.1 it opens the site, but I need to be able to create several configs with different names.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating several configs with different names"?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can’t get to the server"?

Comment: I can’t get to the server at http://hello.dev

Comment: I think you may need to add `hello.dev` to point to `127.0.0.1` in your HOSTS file (if on Windows, probably similar solution if on another OS).